# VBAでMSProjectのタスクモードを判別したい

Tags: vba

VBAを用いてMSProjectのタスクモードが自動スケジュールなのか手動スケジュールなのかを判定させ、動作を変えたいプログラムを作成しているのですが、どう記述すればいいのでしょうか？

参考にしているMicrosoftのデベロッパーセンターにそれらしきプロパティがないので、質問させて頂きました(https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/project.task)。

Comment: [タスクの手動プロパティ (Project)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/project.task.manual) ではありませんか？

Comment: kunifさん> 回答ありがとうございます！manualは盲点でした。。これで試してみようと思います。